# trouble using system-uuid for specific autoinstall config

Tags: cloud-init, uuid, autoinstall

I'm encountering difficulties fetching a specific #cloud-config file based on the SMBIOS UUID during the installation of Ubuntu 22.04 virtual machines using autoinstall. I have a general #cloud-config file located at http:///jammy/cloud-init-bios/user-data that needs to be included by every instance. Additionally, I want to provide a specific #cloud-config file for each instance based on their SMBIOS UUID.

I've attempted to configure the netboot process with the following configuration in my pxelinux.cfg/default file, using the [example supplied by cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/datasources/nocloud.html#:%7E:text=For%20example%2C%20you%20can%20pass%20this%20option%20to%20QEMU%3A).

```
LABEL ubuntu-jammy-autoinstall
    MENU label Install Ubuntu Jammy - autoinstall
    KERNEL ::jammy/vmlinuz 
    INITRD ::jammy/initrd
    APPEND root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000 ip=dhcp fsck.mode=skip url=http://<server-ip>/tftp/images/ubuntu-22.04.2.iso autoinstall -smbios type=1,serial=ds=nocloud-net;s=http://<server-ip>/tftp/meta/__dmi.system-uuid__/ cloud-config-url=http://<server-ip>/jammy/cloud-init-bios/user-data
```

After trying to launch the autoinstaller the client machine seems to skip the sourcefrom line, which should be /tftp/meta/ae166f1a-841a-468d-b0b9-7ddee880f42b/meta-data and go straight to the cloud-config-url.

The logs on my pxeboot server:

```
pxeboot01:80 192.168.10.200 - - [05/Jul/2023:10:28:29 +0200] "GET /tftp/images/ubuntu-22.04.2.iso HTTP/1.1" 200 1975972118 "-" "Wget"
pxeboot01:80 192.168.10.200 - - [05/Jul/2023:10:29:09 +0200] "GET /tftp/jammy/cloud-init-bios/user-data HTTP/1.1" 200 2121 "-" "Cloud-Init/22.4.2-0ubuntu0~22.04.1"
pxeboot01:80 192.168.10.200 - - [05/Jul/2023:10:29:11 +0200] "GET /tftp/jammy/cloud-init-bios/user-data HTTP/1.1" 200 2121 "-" "Cloud-Init/22.4.2-0ubuntu0~22.04.1"
```

When I don't specify the cloud-init-url (only sourcefrom) the installer just fails and falls back into the language selection screen. logs on the client machine don't specify the machine ever doing something with the uuid.